# Radio buttons alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble fixing the alignment of the radio button text. I tried with CSS and many other "tricks", but it won't display the text on the same line as the radio button is. The text is shifted like the first radio button text on [this site](http://shrink-art.com/test/delete2.html).

My code looks like this:

```html
 <p id="Incident1">
  <label>Please select the right option:</label><br /> 
  <label><input id="indt" name="indt" type="radio" value="Incident" />Incident&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label> 
  <label><input id="indt2" name="indt" type="radio" value="Service"/>Service</label>
 </p>
```

Can someone advise me on this?

Comment: ul#delCatflagul span.radioText {    
    margin-top: -1.2em;
}        can you try this css

Comment: This helped me out, thanks.